# Distribute html app on pendrive

Tags: html, offline, usb-drive

I have an html app, with html, js, css and images, which I need to distribute on a pendrive for Mac and PC. When users open the app, however, they're receiving security errors in their browser.

I'm looking for a simple solution to this, but I can't find any easy way of opening a html app from a pen drive. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
You are right The error come from ajax local call to xml files. 
Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: I dont see why it would have security errors with `only` html, css, and js. Will ithave any ajax calls or server side code?

Comment: The situation you describe is unlikely to cause security errors.

Comment: Ya and i agree with both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to question - How can I make local ajax calls to xml files when distributing my html project locally?

The users who are having problems is probably due to the browser they are using and the state the browser was initialised in, as some browsers by default allow local ajax calls to files and some don't.

You have two options.

1. To your users specify a browser to run it in (for example chrome automatically disallows local ajax calls however if started with the flag --allow-file-access-from-files it will allow this behaviour)
2. Host the files on a web-server either in the flash drive or externally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I knew about this solutions, but it's to complicated for the distribution of marketing application.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the solution.

With the mongoose portbla web server, I can launch a small web server without installation on mac an pc.

I just have to find how to put my page as default.

I wish it will help someone with the same problem.